# getting the minimum and maximum date in the same query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a working query that gives me the maxdate:

```
SELECT a.client_id AS client_id
   , a.patientcount AS patientcount
   , received_date AS maxRecDate
FROM
(
   SELECT DISTINCT CLIENT_ID
   , PATIENT_ID
   , count(*) over (partition by client_id, patient_id) AS patientcount
   from f_accession_daily
) AS a
JOIN F_ACCESSION_DAILY AS f ON a.CLIENT_ID = f.CLIENT_ID
   AND a.PATIENT_ID = f.PATIENT_ID
GROUP BY f.RECEIVED_DATE, a.CLIENT_ID, a.patientcount
HAVING f.RECEIVED_DATE = MAX(f.received_date)
```

In the same query I would also like to return min(f.received_date).

Is there a way to do this? perhaps with the subquery?

Comment: for future reference, please provide the structure of your tables escpecially if you question is all about `sql`. it helps alot.

Comment: Are you wanting to put the min date in the having or select?

Comment: @Gizmo i want to be able to return both the max and min dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be missing something, but I don't see why you are grouping by `f.RECEIVED_DATE`

I think the query could be:

```
SELECT a.client_id AS client_id
   , a.patientcount AS patientcount
   , max(f.received_date) AS maxRecDate
   , min(f.received_date) AS minRecDate
FROM
(
   SELECT DISTINCT CLIENT_ID
   , PATIENT_ID
   , count(*) over (partition by client_id, patient_id) AS patientcount
   from f_accession_daily
) AS a
JOIN F_ACCESSION_DAILY AS f ON a.CLIENT_ID = f.CLIENT_ID
   AND a.PATIENT_ID = f.PATIENT_ID
GROUP BY a.CLIENT_ID, a.patientcount
```

I haven't tested this, but I think it should work.

Answer (score 1):

In your query, add an OR condition to check for MIN date as well. Solves the problem

```
SELECT a.client_id AS client_id
, a.patientcount AS patientcount
, received_date AS maxRecDate
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT CLIENT_ID
, PATIENT_ID
, count(*) over (partition by client_id, patient_id) AS patientcount
from f_accession_daily
) AS a
JOIN F_ACCESSION_DAILY AS f ON a.CLIENT_ID = f.CLIENT_ID
AND a.PATIENT_ID = f.PATIENT_ID
GROUP BY f.RECEIVED_DATE, a.CLIENT_ID, a.patientcount
HAVING f.RECEIVED_DATE = MAX(f.received_date) 
OR f.RECEIVED_DATE = MIN(f.received_date) -- Newly added condition
```

Comment: thank you so much this is almost perfect. the thing is i need to select BOTH max and min for the same client and patient